# how to do a li with two lines?

Tags: html, css

need do a navbar with a ul, but one link have one li with two lines, i need follow the design of .psd file. how i can do this?
below you can see the navbar screenshot of psd file, and my source code made by myself with html/css.

[image: this is my navbar on psd file. the "informativos tecnicos" have two lines]

this is the source of my navbar:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xKL9/

```
<div class="sub-menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="empresa" class="">empresa</a>
            <div class="sub-empresa">
                <ul class="menu-empresa">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("historia"); ?>">história</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('politica_de_privacidade') ?>">política de privacidade</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('certificacoes') ?>">certificações e prêmios</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="pipe"></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('produtos') ?>">produtos</a></li>
        <li class="pipe"></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('representantes') ?>">representantes</a></li>
        <li class="pipe"></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('distribuidores') ?>">eletricista</a></li>
        <li class="pipe"></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('informativo_tecnico') ?>" id="infotec">informativos tecnicos</a>
            <div class="sub-informativo-tec">
                <ul class="menu-infotec">
                    <li><a href="#">generalidades</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('informativo_tecnico_simbologia_instalacao') ?>">recomendações para instalações</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('informativo_tecnico_conceitos_basicos') ?>">conceitos básicos sobre condutores</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('informativo_tecnico_simbologia') ?>">simbologia</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('informativo_tecnico_criterio_dimensionamento_circuito') ?>">critério de dimensionamento de circuitos</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('informativo_tecnico_queda_tensao') ?>">queda de tensão</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">dimencionamento de eletrodutos</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('informativo_tecnico_correntes_maximas') ?>">correntes máximas de curto-circuito</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="pipe"></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('eventos') ?>">eventos</a></li>
        <li class="pipe"></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('videos') ?>">videos</a></li>
        <li class="pipe"></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="contato">fale conosco</a>
            <div class="sub-fale-conosco">
                <ul class="menu-faleconosco">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('fale_conosco') ?>">fale conosco</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('trabalhe_conosco') ?>">trabalhe conosco</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">seja nosso representante</a></li>
                    <li class="separador"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">seja nosso distribuidor</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul><!-- /.menu -->
</div><!-- /.sub-menu -->
```

Comment: Just replace spaces with line breaks (let me suppose you can't set e maximum width because it's unknown and may be different for each item).

Comment: if i do it, two blocks of background appear when link is hovered for each word. try it in my jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
vertical-align: middle
```

along with

```
max-width
```

to achieve the effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xKL9/1/

remove the padding to prevent the hovering issue: http://jsfiddle.net/6xKL9/5/

note that vertical-align only works with elements which are inline and you can only set sizes for elements which are blocks so i've made the  inline-block in order to enjoy both worlds.

Comment: it work, but the only issue is the link when is hovered. break out of navbar.

Answer (score 1):

Set `display: table-caption;` on your links. This triggers a new line for each word.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/6xKL9/4/)**

```
.sub-menu .menu li a {
  ...
  display: table-caption; /* <-- */
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Nice but this does not align the text vertically with the other list items which was a requirement.

Comment: hi daniel, your solution work too, but, other links break to down. how improve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a line break

```
<br>
```

So for your example:

```
<li>informativos<br>tecnicos</li>
```